# How can I make some basic javascript animations dynamic?

Tags: javascript

I use the following JavaScript animation to make a few images slide in from the right of the screen when my website loads:

```
var step=8; var step1=16; var step2=12; var step3=6; var step4=4;
function move_img(str) {

var a=document.getElementById('i1').offsetTop; a= a +100;
document.getElementById('i1').style.top= a + "px";

var b=document.getElementById('i2').offsetTop; b= b +100;
document.getElementById('i2').style.top= b + "px";

var c=document.getElementById('i3').offsetTop; c= c +100;
document.getElementById('i3').style.top= c + "px";

var d=document.getElementById('i4').offsetTop; d= d +100;
document.getElementById('i4').style.top= d + "px";

var e=document.getElementById('i5').offsetTop; e= e +100;
document.getElementById('i5').style.top= e + "px"; }

function disp(){

var a=document.getElementById('i1').offsetLeft; var
b=document.getElementById('i2').offsetLeft; var
c=document.getElementById('i3').offsetLeft; var
d=document.getElementById('i4').offsetLeft; var
e=document.getElementById('i5').offsetLeft; if(a > 400){a= a - step;
document.getElementById('i1').style.left= a + "px"; // horizontal
movment step *=0.9948; } if(b > 200 ){b= b - step1;
document.getElementById('i2').style.left= b + "px"; // horizontal
movment step1*=0.992; }

if(c > 350 ){c = c - step2; document.getElementById('i3').style.left=
c + "px"; // horizontal movment step2*=0.993; }

if(d > 1200 ){d = d - step3; document.getElementById('i4').style.left=
d + "px"; // horizontal movment step3*=0.997; } if(e > 1350 ){e = e -
step4; document.getElementById('i5').style.left= e + "px"; //
horizontal movment step4*=0.998; } }

function timer(){ disp(); my_time=setTimeout('timer()',10);

}
```

While this looks great on my computer, since it uses pixels instead of percents, it looks bad in different aspect ratios. How can I fix this?

Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if you have to use Javascript, but you do know you can achieve this with [CSS3](http://www.developerdrive.com/2012/02/moving-web-page-elements-using-the-css3-translate-transform/)? Much less headache.

Comment: Use CSS, and maybe on load change the class names of the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I prepare example of using CSS3 `transition`. Here is a class which have transition rule. On demo you can see how it can be done.

```
.animate{
    left: 0;
    width: 50px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s;
    transition: all 1s;
}
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GtGEz/1/show/)

---

Another case using CSS3 `animation`:

### [DEMO - Animation](http://jsfiddle.net/uwpgY/1/show/)

Comment: Thank you, much easier than javascript

Comment: and better for browser. But be careful. If you need write code for oldest browser you must change mind because some of them (yes yes I mean IE :D) doesn't support this feautures.

Answer (score 0):

Make the dimension changes relative to window size.

[Here's a blog with details on cross-browser ways to get window/viewport dimensions with javascript](http://andylangton.co.uk/blog/development/get-viewport-size-width-and-height-javascript)

But if you're willing to support only browsers which can use CSS3, as suggested by others, CSS is probably a cleaner, more efficient way to achieve the effect you're wanting